# Why did Canon name the first Digital Rebel 300D?

Tags: canon

All Canon EOS Digital SLR cameras seem to follow a logical progression except for the D30 and D60 which were named for their megapixel size.

Why did Canon not name the first Digital Rebel 100D?

Comment: How was naming the 50D replacement 7D while at the same time introducing a 60D that was in several ways a downgrade from the 50D a logical progression? How was introducing a lower grade than the Rebel xx0D series with an xx00D series and then later creating a tier between the xx0D series (then at the 700D) and the xx00D series (then at the 1100D) with another xx0D series starting at 100D logical?

Comment: If engineers named the models, they'd start at 1, and just increment. Model names are chosen by marketeers, so this is a marketing consideration, not a photographic one. Also, in marketing, there's no right and wrong, only ideas and decisions that either work or don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the person(s) at Canon who made the decision at the time could say definitively. For anyone else, it's just a guess. But there may be a likely scenario.

There had already been an [EOS 100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_100) camera. It was a 35mm film camera introduced in 1991 and marketed in North America as the EOS Elan. It was a model aimed at advanced amateur photographers. Unfortunately, the internal connection between the main control dial and the electrical switches moved by the dial was prone to breaking in the EOS 100. *At the dawn of the digital DSLR age it was probably thought that an EOS 100D would be too easily confused with the EOS 100, which had a couple of known manufacturing issues and was discontinued in 1995.*

The EOS 100 was likely still viewed in a negative light by more than a few Canon customers when the first Digital Rebel was introduced. There were still used EOS 100 cameras on the market for sale very cheaply over a decade after it was discontinued (and several years after the 300D had taken the world by storm!) - mainly because no one wanted them. Canon probably wanted to avoid the risk of anyone associating their new consumer DSLR with one of the biggest clunkers in the entire line of EOS film cameras.

As to why they didn't start with the EOS 200D your guess is as good as mine, since to the best of my knowledge there has never been an EOS 200.

The EOS 300, on the other hand, was a more recent and very successful film camera at the time the 300D was introduced to the market. Canon likely welcomed an association of their new consumer DSLR, the Digital Rebel/300D, with the EOS 300 film camera.

Comment: The difference is the 300D was a very successful model. The EOS 100 was perceived as a clunker and Canon probably didn't want their new consumer grade DSLR (the world's first sub $1,000 DSLR) associated with the model number.

Comment: The 10-series was only on the market a couple of years and sold in limited numbers before being replaced by the EOS 5/A2/A2E in 1992 when multiple AF points (controlled by eye movement!) were introduced. It was by and large a forgettable model that appeared and disappeared quickly when more advanced AF technology made the replacement the one to remember. By the time the 10D was introduced a decade later there probably weren't *that* many people who even remembered there had ever been an EOS 10 film camera.

Comment: On the other hand, the EOS 100 sold in modestly high enough numbers for long enough that there were plenty floating around on the used market for quite a while - partly because no one wanted them. They had an issue with the main dial that was prone to break off internally making the camera pretty much useless,even though it did not appear to be damaged without testing. With film. That had to be developed before you could see if exposure was correct.

Comment: My first comment above should be about the EOS 300 (not 300D), which was a very successful model. Canon probably *wanted* buyers to make an association with that model, unlike the EOS 100.

Comment: It does appear that Canon wanted to make a connection with the EOS 300 and EOS 300V film cameras and the new EOS 300D digital camera.  They were all similar in size and looks, and all had a 7 point AF system. http://preview.tinyurl.com/jcm4uvn